# Users can't save new article in backend (buttons does not show)

Tags: administrator, com-content, acl, administration, article-manager

I've got an annoying problem and can't solve it.

I need to create a lower-level admin access in my website backend, which can only create and edit articles.
I started creating a new group (Admin Users), and assign it "Special" and "Super Users" Access Levels.

After i gave to this group some permission:

1. From "Global Configuration": "Administration Access"
2. From "Content" component: "Administration Access", "Create", "Delete", "Edit", "Edit State" and "Edit Own Elements".

(My backend language is Italian, so there can be some different names of options).

When I'm trying to create a new article there aren't any "Save" button, and can't select "State" and "Category"... see the image below:

[image: Create New Article Area]

Have you got an idea about solving this issue?

Clearing browser cache, restart and login can't solve this problem.
Alle plugins are up to date and Joomla release is 3.4.4

Comment: you can also update the Joomla version

Comment: Maybe try clearing the Joomla cache too.

Comment: @user2132234 please do not leave abandoned questions.  Please "accept" the answer below or update your question with where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the permission of your new created group for this action:

Menu System >> Global Configuration >> Articles >>
Tab "Permissions" >>

Click in your new created group (in this example was "manager");

Check the permissions for your new created group:

[image]